# VIM: I need a vim colorscheme like gedit classic/default color

Tags: vim, editor, gedit

The default gedit colorscheme is classic.

How can i get the same colorscheme for vim ?

That means vim will have a colorscheme like gedit classic/default scheme.

Comment: I don't think SO is the place for this question, but look at http://vimcolorschemetest.googlecode.com/svn/html/index-java.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you can take a look here:

http://code.google.com/p/vimcolorschemetest/

they have 428 (so far) color schemes (with screenshot) on different language highlights. pick one you liked. ;)

Most light-schemes are at almost end of the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the color scheme in vim by doing:

```
colorscheme <scheme>
```

As for the available color schemes look [here](http://technosophos.com/content/vim-colorschemes).

Comment: I know how to change the colorscheme on vim. I'm searching a similar colorshcme like gedit classic/default.